# How to toggle Angular material expansion panel programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I just started working on an Angular 4 project with material design.

I am currently working with the expansion component, [the API states](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) that  *a disabled expansion panel can't be toggled by the user, but can still be manipulated programmatically*. I don't know however, how you can toggle your panel programmatically.

What is the preferred way in Angular to simulate this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`expanded` is set to `true` to expand the expansion panel and set to `false` to close the expansion panel. In the following example, expansion panel is programmatically opened and closed. [Please refer this link](https://plnkr.co/edit/iLUkCUDCSM6fygeQFadA?p=preview)

TS file

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Expansion panel as accordion
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'expansion-steps-example',
    templateUrl: 'expansion-steps-example.html',
    styleUrls: ['expansion-steps-example.css']
})
export class ExpansionStepsExample {
    step = 0;

    setStep(index: number) {
        this.step = index;
    }

    nextStep() {
        this.step++;
    }

    prevStep() {
        this.step--;
    }
}
```

HTML file

```html
<mat-accordion class="example-headers-align">
    <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === 0" (opened)="setStep(0)" hideToggle="true">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                Personal data
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
                Type your name and age
                <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="First name">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="number" min="1" placeholder="Age">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-action-row>
            <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="nextStep()">Next</button>
        </mat-action-row>
    </mat-expansion-panel>

    <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === 1" (opened)="setStep(1)" hideToggle="true">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                Destination
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
                Type the country name
                <mat-icon>map</mat-icon>
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Country">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-action-row>
            <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="prevStep()">Previous</button>
            <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="nextStep()">Next</button>
        </mat-action-row>
    </mat-expansion-panel>

    <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === 2" (opened)="setStep(2)" hideToggle="true">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                Day of the trip
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
                Inform the date you wish to travel
                <mat-icon>date_range</mat-icon>
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Date" [matDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()" readonly>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>

        <mat-action-row>
            <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="prevStep()">Previous</button>
            <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="nextStep()">End</button>
        </mat-action-row>
    </mat-expansion-panel>

</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: Can do this in a loop too: <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"><mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step===i" (opened)="step=i">

Comment: @Kim T did you done this in a loop too: <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"><mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step===i" (opened)="step=i">

Comment: @KimT you solution works fine. thanks for the tip :)

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work if you want multiple panel expanded

Answer (score 17):

Another very simple way to handle Mat Expansion panel programmatically is by using **local references in Angular**

```html
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel #mep="matExpansionPanel">
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Now in HTML(not accessible directly in TS file until we use @ViewChild) file use mep to expand or collapse Expansion panel using something like this:

```html
<button (click)="mep.expanded = true;">Expand</button>
<button (click)="mep.expanded = false;">Collapse</button>
```

Comment: This is the right way to go for the accordion and for a set of expansion panels that are not on a complex loop without setting up anything on the component just to track states. On an accordion which is not `multi` you want to call the `.closeAll()` method of the accordion on successful interaction inside any panel. The API has methods for the accordion and for the expansion panels closeAll, open, close & toggle. I think the question is more on how to use those methods instead of knowing much about the template loop or nested loop of items.

Comment: Great solution. I had clickable components inside the Expansion Panel and I wanted to have the panel close if one of the components inside the panel was clicked.  So I had the #mep reference as shown above and then I had the `(click)="mep.expanded = false"` defined for the component right inside the body of that same panel.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 16):

Simple implementation for array of panels

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="indexExpanded == i" disabled="true" *ngFor="...; let i = index">
    ...
    <button (click)="togglePanels(i)">Toggle</button>
    ...
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

And in code

```
indexExpanded: number = -1;

togglePanels(index: number) {
    this.indexExpanded = index == this.indexExpanded ? -1 : index;
}
```

Comment: Much better solution IMO. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 12):

You can set a var, in this case I used "isExpanded" then use it to open and close set the boolean value.

```html
<mat-expansion-panel
    *ngIf="advertisements.objs"
    [expanded]="isExpanded"
>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

If you want to use it with the integrated toogle button instead you must update the "isExpanded" var with the "(opened)" and "(closed)" hooks from mat-expansion-panel.

```html
<mat-expansion-panel
    *ngIf="advertisements.objs"
    [expanded]="isExpanded"
    (opened)="isExpanded = true"
    (closed)="isExpanded = false"
>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: This should be the preferred answer!!

Comment: Perfect. Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

app.component.html:

```html
<button (click)='xpandStatus = !xpandStatus'>Toggle it</button>
<p>
    <mat-expansion-panel [(expanded)]="xpandStatus">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>This an expansion panel</mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>xpandStatus is {{xpandStatus}}</mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        Two-way binding on the expanded attribute gives us a way to store and manipulate the expansion status.
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</p>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    xpandStatus = true;
}
```

Here it is live in StackBlitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtsqg8

Comment: It's suffiient to write `(click)='xpandStatus=!xpandStatus` - just for update

Comment: Agree @LeO, yes its cleaner

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you are looking for the way to trigger open() method from the component on button click, this is what I've been able to get from the material API documentation.

```js
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatAccordion, MatExpansionPanel } from '@angular/material/expansion';
    
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(MatExpansionPanel) pannel?: MatExpansionPanel; 
    @ViewChild(MatAccordion) accordion?: MatAccordion;
    
    constructor(){}
    
    closePannel() { // for expansion panel only
        if(!this.pannel) { return }
        this.pannel.close();
    }
    
    closeAll() { // for all panels in accordion
        if(!this.accordion) { return }
        this.accordion.closeAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works welll for me. thanks